# adding a button on top of video

Tags: html, video

I have tried every post out there to get this right and have given up. I am trying to get a button on top of the video. I know it has to do with the CSS and I am not a genius with it. Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong with the CSS?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxWCt.png)

```css
.video-background {
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
 top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
 height: 325px;
    min-height: 25rem;
 min-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
 overflow: hidden;
} 

 ._pattern-overlay { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 100;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: url(styles/fusiongamer/xenforo/gridtile4x4.gif);
  z-index: 2;
 }
.discordbutton {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 12px 40px;
    border: 1px solid #133b68;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: #236ec3;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#236ec3), to(#133b68));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #236ec3, #133b68);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #236ec3, #133b68);
    font: normal normal bold 20px arial;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.discordbutton:focus {
    border: 1px solid #16457a;
    background: #2a84ea;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#2a84ea), to(#17477d));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2a84ea, #17477d);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2a84ea, #17477d);
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.discordbutton:active {
    background: #133b68;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#133b68), to(#133b68));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #133b68, #133b68);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #133b68, #133b68);
}
```

```html
<div class="video-background">
 <div class="_pattern-overlay"></div>
<video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop">
     <source src="styles/fusiongamer/xenforo/star_citizen.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
</div>
<div class="button_cont" align="center">
<a class="discordbutton" href="https://discord.gg/e4ftHBZ">Join Us</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the button with `position: absolute`, set its `z-index` to make it visible over the video and then you can position it wherever you want.

```css
.video-background {
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
 top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
 height: 325px;
    min-height: 25rem;
 min-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
 overflow: hidden;
} 

 ._pattern-overlay { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 100;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: url(styles/fusiongamer/xenforo/gridtile4x4.gif);
  z-index: 2;
 }
.discordbutton {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 12px 40px;
    border: 1px solid #133b68;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: #236ec3;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#236ec3), to(#133b68));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #236ec3, #133b68);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #236ec3, #133b68);
    font: normal normal bold 20px arial;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.discordbutton:focus {
    border: 1px solid #16457a;
    background: #2a84ea;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#2a84ea), to(#17477d));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2a84ea, #17477d);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2a84ea, #17477d);
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.discordbutton:active {
    background: #133b68;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#133b68), to(#133b68));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #133b68, #133b68);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #133b68, #133b68);
}
```

```html
<div class="video-background">
 <div class="_pattern-overlay"></div>
    <video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" 
    loop="loop">
     <source src="styles/fusiongamer/xenforo/star_citizen.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
      <a class="discordbutton" href="https://discord.gg/e4ftHBZ">Join Us</a>
</div>
```

Actually, in your case this `z-index` is required only because you have set `z-index` to `.video-background`.
And regarding the positioning of the button, I suggest you getting familiar with [CSS positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). Considering your example, it will be better if you move the button inside the `.video-background` element, since it is with `position: relative` - you will be able to set the button offsets easily.

Comment: Now it moved it way to the right and not on the video.

Comment: Did you try to move the button inside `div class="video-background"` ?

Comment: I updated the HTML snippet, you can give it one more try.